# Ruby - Grouping and Projection

Tags: ruby

Coming from c#, I'm used to being able to do the following using LINQ

```
var people = new List<Person> 
{
    new Person(Race.Black, "Mitch",30),
    new Person(Race.White, "Mike",30),
    new Person(Race.Mexican, "Mel",30),
};

var groups = people.GroupBy (p => p.Race)
                 .Select(g => new {race = g.Key, person = g});
```

Moving into Ruby, I would like to do grouping and projection into a hash, but is there an out of the box method for this or do I need to roll my own?  Here's my implementation but it'd be great if this was offered in the language, or a 3rd party library that offered an implementation

```
def group(arr,group_sym)
  groups = {}
  arr.each do |i|
    race = i[group_sym]
    groups[race] = [] unless groups.has_key?(race)
    i.delete(group_sym)
    groups[race].push(i)
  end

  groups
end
```

Edit: So what I'm expecting from this is the following:

input:

```
people = [{name: 'mike', race: 'white', age: 30},
{name: 'mel', race: 'white', age: 31},
{name: 'mitch', race: 'black', age: 30},
{name: 'megan', race: 'asian', age: 30},
{name: 'maebe', race: 'black', age: 30},]
```

function call:

```
groupedPeople = groupBy(people,'race')
```

returns:

```
[{'white' => [{name: 'mike', age: 30},
{name: 'mel', race: 'white'}],
{'black' => [{...black people}],
{'asian' => [{...asian people}]


}]
```

For this specific example, I'd want to get a hash where my people array is grouped by race

Comment: It's better to provide a simple example input and expected result.

Comment: Is your goal to obtain a group of people by race name and age?

Comment: @Ifender Yes, it's to get a hash where people are grouped by race (i.e. the key of the hash is race)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the fact that C#'s query expressions are meant to look like SQL queries, the method names are a bit unusual compared to other languages: `Select` is usually called `map`, `Aggregate` is usually called `fold` or `reduce`, `Where` is usually called `select` or `filter`, etc.

If you simply translate the method names, you can almost literally translate your code to Ruby:

```
Person = Struct.new(:race, :name, :age)

people = [
  Person.new(:black,   'Mitch', 30), 
  Person.new(:white,   'Mike',  30), 
  Person.new(:mexican, 'Mel',   30)
]

groups = people.group_by(&:race).map {|race, people| { race: race, person: people } }
```

I used a `Hash` as the closest replacement for `IGrouping`.

Comment: This looks promising, i'll try this out tonight. Thanks